# Understanding isomorphic equivalences of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

I get some big picture of tensor and tensor product by reading their Wikipedia articles, and several questions and answers posted before by others. But I cannot figure out how to show the following isomorphic equivalences:

1. from [Zach Conn](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors/10291#10291):

   > For finite-dimensional spaces V,W, the tensor product $V^* \otimes W$ is
   >   isomorphic to the space of homomorphisms $\textrm{Hom}(V, W)$. So in other
   >   words
   >   every linear map $V \to W$ has a tensor expansion, i.e., a
   >   representation as 
   >   a tensor in $V^* \otimes W$.

   I wonder why "the tensor product $V^* \otimes W$ is isomorphic to the space of homomorphisms $\textrm{Hom}(V,W)$"?
2. from [Hans Lundmark](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors/10374#10374):

   > a bilinear map $B:V \times U \to \mathbb{R}$ can be canonically identified with an
   >   element
   >   of the space $V^* \otimes U^*$.

   How is a bilinear map $B:V \times U \to \mathbb{R}$ canonically identified with an
   element of the space $V^* \otimes U^*$?
3. from [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13010/tensors-as-matrices-vs-tensors-as-multi-linear-maps/13012#13012):

   > - A linear transformation $V \to V$,
   > - An element of $V^* \otimes V$,
   > - A linear map $V \otimes V^* \to \mathbb{R} $.
   >
   > The identification (of the first) with the second picture comes
   >   from the fact that
   >   dual distributes over tensor product (which again comes down to
   >   tensor
   >   contraction) and the fact that $V^{**} \cong V$. Alternately, again by
   >   tensor
   >   contraction, there is a natural bilinear map $V \times (V^* \otimes V) \to V$ which
   >   identifies an element of $V^* \otimes V$ with a linear transformation $V \to V$.

   How does that dual distributes over tensor product
   come from tensor contraction, and how does this lead to the identification?

   How is the natural bilinear map $V \times (V^* \otimes V) \to V$ defined?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Hint for 1. Try first to define a linear map from the tensor product to the Hom space. [Suggestions: define $R$, try to improve the formatting...]

Comment: @Tim: You should choose a definition of tensor product, otherwise it is not clear what the appropriate answer to each of your questions is.

Comment: Dear @Zhen. Thanks for the edit. Can't we assume that the tensor product is defined by the usual universal property?

Comment: @Zhen: The definition of tensor product I used is by a bilinear mapping with universal property.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll attempt to sketch some of these maps below.

1. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$Let's try to define a linear map $\Phi\colon V^* \otimes W \to \Hom(V, W)$. We know that this is the same as giving a bilinear $V^* \times W \to \Hom(V, W)$. Now, given a functional $f\colon V \to \mathbf{R}$ and an element $w \in W$, I can produce a linear map $V \to W$ that sends $x \mapsto f(x)w$.

   To see that this is surjective [which is enough, since the dimensions match up], pick a basis $\{v_i\}$ of $V$ and a basis $\{w_i\}$ of $W$. Let $\{v_i^*\}$ be the dual basis to $\{v_i\}$. Then $$\Phi(v_i^* \otimes w_j)(v_k) = \delta_{ik}w_j.$$
   So this sends $v_i$ to $w_j$, and sends all other $v_j$, $j \neq i$ to zero. These maps certainly span $\Hom(V, W)$.
2. We want a bilinear map $V^* \times U^* \to \operatorname{Bilin}(V, U)$. If $f\colon V \to \mathbf{R}$ and $g\colon U \to \mathbf {R}$ are functionals, there is nothing more bilinear than multiplication: define $V \times U \to \mathbf{R}$ by $(x, y) \mapsto f(x)g(y)$.
3. It's not clear to me what Qiaochu meant here, so I must be missing something. This actually follows from (2), since that part will show that giving an element of $V^* \otimes U^*$ is the same as giving a bilinear $V \times U \to \mathbf{R}$, and that's the same as an element of $(V \otimes U)^*$.

Comment: +1!Very nice! About 1.: I would have avoided describing the inverse isomorphism. I would have used the fact the linear maps are sums of rank one linear maps to prove the surjectivity. I must be missing something ...

Comment: That is probably the nicest way to prove that it's an isomorphism, yes! But I remember the inverse having some significance. I'll look around.

Answer (score 14):

I'll note that there is a slightly different universal property the tensor product satisfies: for any three vector spaces $U, V, W$ over a common field $k$, there is an isomorphism
$$\textrm{Hom}(U \otimes V, W) \cong \textrm{Hom}(U, \textrm{Hom}(V, W))$$
which is moreover natural in $U$ (contravariantly), $W$ (covariantly) and $V$ (extraordinarily). Taking $W = k$ yields the usual universal property in terms of bilinear maps. (A bilinear map $U \times V \to k$, after all, is essentially the same thing as a linear map $U \to \textrm{Hom}(V, k)$.)

The above *adjunction property* yields an alternative abstract-nonsense answer for the first question, if we take the isomorphism $(U \otimes V)^* \cong U^* \otimes V^*$ for granted. Recall that every finite-dimensional vector space is naturally isomorphic to its double dual. So, if $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces,
$$U^* \otimes V \cong \textrm{Hom}((U^* \otimes V)^*, k) \cong \textrm{Hom}(U^{**} \otimes V^*, k) \cong \textrm{Hom}(U^{**}, V^{**}) \cong \textrm{Hom}(U, V)$$
Obviously, this proof doesn't work when either $U$ or $V$ are infinite-dimensional. (In fact, [the claim isn't even true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57204/tensor-products-of-infinite-dimensional-spaces-and-other-objects).)

Dylan's answer adequately addresses the second question, so I'll skip that.

As for the third question, I too am not sure what Qiaochu meant. To me, tensor contraction is the linear map $U^* \otimes U \to k$ which is obtained from the bilinear map $U^* \times U \to k$ given by $(\alpha, v) \mapsto \alpha (v)$. If you think of $U^* \otimes U$ as being a space of matrices, this is just the trace map.

The natural bilinear map $\epsilon : V \times (V^* \otimes V) \to V$ Qiaochu is alluding to is the map given by $(v, \alpha \otimes v') \mapsto \alpha(v) v'$. In other words, it is the result of evaluating an element of $V^* \otimes V$, regarded as a linear map $V \to V$, at $v$. (But there is *another* natural bilinear map, namely the one given by $(v, \alpha \otimes v') \mapsto \alpha(v') v$. I'm quite sure this isn't the one he meant.) Another way of getting $\epsilon$ is by considering what happens to the map $V^* \otimes V \to \textrm{Hom}(V, V)$ from the first question under the isomorphism
$$\textrm{Hom}((V^* \otimes V) \otimes V, V) \cong \textrm{Hom}(V^* \otimes V, \textrm{Hom}(V, V))$$

As for the connection with tensor contraction: note that there is a natural isomorphism $V \otimes (V^* \otimes V) \cong (V \otimes V^*) \otimes V$, and a natural isomorphism $V \otimes V^* \cong V^* \otimes V$; the map $\epsilon$ is essentially the composition of the trace map with these isomorphisms.

Comment: Tensor contraction is the result of pairing together any factor of $V$ with any factor of $V^{\ast}$ in a tensor product of vector spaces under the evaluation map. The map I had in mind is a special case of the map $V \otimes (V^{\ast} \otimes W) \to W$ (so the first two factors are supposed to be paired).