# Tensored vectorspaces isomorphic to the endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding isomorphic equivalences of tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57189/understanding-isomorphic-equivalences-of-tensor-product)

I have the following question: Let $V$ be a vectorspace with an inner product $<.,.>$. Let $V^{*}$ be its dual. Is it true that $V \otimes V^{*} = End(V)$ ? If yes in which way ? what is the isomorpism ? Thanks in advance.

mika

Comment: It is only true if $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: is there any coordinate free isomorphism ?

Comment: @mika Dear mika, I believe the definition of the isomorphism in the question I linked is coordinate-free. To prove that it _is_ an isomorphism it seems to me that you must choose a basis, since the result may not be true outside of the finite case. I can add more detail there, if you like. Cheers,

Comment: sure. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the inner product. It's true more generally that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $W$ is any vector space whatsoever, then $V^{\ast} \otimes W$ is canonically isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(V, W)$; that is, the two are naturally isomorphic functors $\text{FinVect}^{op} \times \text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}$ (so in particular they are isomorphic as $\text{GL}(V) \times \text{GL}(W)$-representations, which is a much stronger statement than that they are isomorphic as vector spaces). The isomorphism sends a pure tensor $f \otimes w$ to the map
$$v \mapsto f(v) w$$

where $v \in V$.